# В чем разница между командами для автозагрузки приложения с отсрочкой с помощью sleep (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sleep, автозагрузка

Всем привет,
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница в подходах для запуска приложений через автозагрузку с помощью команды sleep?

Изначально задача довольно тривиальная, запустить какую либо программу после входа пользователя в систему. На просторах интернета отыскал гайд, в котором указывается что необходимо отредактировать строку "exec=" в "~/.config/autostart/some_user_app.desktop", добавив в эту строку команду sleep <some_value>; далее команду на запуск непосредственно приложения, но это не сработало.
Пример кода:

`Exec=sleep 10; gnome-terminal`
// Почему это не сработало?

`Exec=bash -c 'sleep 10; gnome-terminal'`
// Почему сработала эта конструкция?

Заранее благодарю за пояснение

Comment: Название `Exec` намекает, что там передается путь к исполняемому файлу и аргументы, а не скрипт для интерпретатора командной строки.

Comment: @user7860670 
Т.е. в данном случае я использую bash, для того чтоб открыть bash - терминал. Правильно ли я понимаю эту конструкцию?

Comment: вы используете программу bash для того, чтобы запустить программу gnome-terminal.

Comment: Искренне спасибо всем за разъяснение!